# Why I cannot see caret icon?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have created left navigation menu by referring this artilce - https://www.codehim.com/bootstrap/bootstrap-vertical-menu-with-submenu-on-click/ but I cannot see `fa-caret-up fa-caret-down` for 'Setting' and 'Help' menu item.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 5 Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
 
  <style>
  
  nav {
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px;
    width: 360px;
    background-color: black;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}
nav ul li {
  /* Sub Menu */
   
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
   
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: 0.2s linear;
    transition: 0.2s linear;
    
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #1d4f71;
    color: #fff;
}
nav ul li a .fa {
    width: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 5px;
    float:right;
}
nav ul ul {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
nav ul li ul li a {
    
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
nav ul li ul li a:hover {

    border-left: 4px solid #3498db;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class='animated bounceInDown '>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#profile'>Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href='#message'>Messages</a></li>
        <li class='sub-menu'><a href='#settings'>Settings<div class='fa fa-caret-down right'></div></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#settings'>Account</a></li>
                <li><a href='#settings'>Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href='#settings'>Secruity & Privacy</a></li>
                <li><a href='#settings'>Password</a></li>
                <li><a href='#settings'>Notification</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='sub-menu'><a href='#message'>Help<div class='fa fa-caret-down right'></div></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#settings'>FAQ's</a></li>
                <li><a href='#settings'>Submit a Ticket</a></li>
                <li><a href='#settings'>Network Status</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#message'>Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

 <script>
      $('.sub-menu ul').hide();
$(".sub-menu a").click(function () {
    $(this).parent(".sub-menu").children("ul").slideToggle("100");
    $(this).find(".right").toggleClass("fa-caret-up fa-caret-down");
});
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Could you please let me know what is the wrong in above code?

Comment: yes. I mean menu is working fine but I cannot see icon <div class='fa fa-caret-down right'>  on right side of 'Setting' text during run time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FontAwesome is usually used along with italic elements, e.g: `<i class='fa fa-caret-down right'></i>`.

You were also not linking the FontAwesome stylesheet, meaning there was nothing to intercept your classes to append the icons:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 5 Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
 
  <style>
  
  nav {
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px;
    width: 360px;
    background-color: black;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}
nav ul li {
  /* Sub Menu */
   
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
   
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: 0.2s linear;
    transition: 0.2s linear;
    
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #1d4f71;
    color: #fff;
}
nav ul li a .fa {
    width: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 5px;
    float:right;
}
nav ul ul {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
nav ul li ul li a {
    
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
nav ul li ul li a:hover {

    border-left: 4px solid #3498db;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class='animated bounceInDown '>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#profile'>Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href='#message'>Messages</a></li>
        <li class='sub-menu'><a href='#settings'>Settings<i class='fa fa-caret-down right'></i></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#settings'>Account</a></li>
                <li><a href='#settings'>Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href='#settings'>Secruity & Privacy</a></li>
                <li><a href='#settings'>Password</a></li>
                <li><a href='#settings'>Notification</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='sub-menu'><a href='#message'>Help<i class='fa fa-caret-down right'></i></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#settings'>FAQ's</a></li>
                <li><a href='#settings'>Submit a Ticket</a></li>
                <li><a href='#settings'>Network Status</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#message'>Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

 <script>
      $('.sub-menu ul').hide();
$(".sub-menu a").click(function () {
    $(this).parent(".sub-menu").children("ul").slideToggle("100");
    $(this).find(".right").toggleClass("fa-caret-up fa-caret-down");
});
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```